# Powershell read shellcode from file

Tags: windows, powershell, shellcode

I have a powershell script which execute the shellcode.

```
$code = 0xe8,0x3b,0x3d,0x03,0x00,0x3b,0x3d,0x03
$code.GetType()
[Byte[]] $buf = $code
$buf.Length
```

The output of above command is

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
8
```

But when i save the shellcode in text file and executes it, it doesn't execute and buffer length is also different.

```
$codes = @(Get-Content -Raw C:\Users\abc\Downloads\code.txt)
$codes.GetType()
[Byte[]] $buf = $codes.ToCharArray()
echo $buf.Length
```

The Output of above command

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
39
```

By any chance can i execute the above shellcode from text file and keeping the buffer length same.

Comment: You want `Get-Content C:\Users\abc\Downloads\code.txt -Encoding Byte` (or `Get-Content C:\Users\abc\Downloads\code.txt -AsByteStream` in PowerShell 7)

Comment: Even Trying @(Get-Content C:\Users\abc\Downloads\code.txt -Encoding Byte) the result is same.

Comment: Then you probably have the literal string `0xe8,0x3b,0x3d,0x03,0x00,0x3b,0x3d,0x03` stored in the file, see the second suggestion in my answer below :)

Comment: The file consist long list of shellcode the above shellcode was snippet of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file consists of 8 bytes, use `Get-Content -Encoding Byte`:

```
# Windows PowerShell
$codes = @(Get-Content C:\Users\abc\Downloads\code.txt -Encoding Byte)

# PowerShell 7
$codes = @(Get-Content C:\Users\abc\Downloads\code.txt -AsByteStream)
```

If the file instead contains the literal string `0xe8,0x3b,0x3d,0x03,0x00,0x3b,0x3d,0x03`, you'll need to split up the list and parse them as numerical values first:

```
$codes = @(Get-Content -Raw C:\Users\abc\Downloads\code.txt)
$codes = $codes.Trim() -split '(?s)[\s,]+' -as [byte[]]
```

Comment: The file consist long list of shellcode the above shellcode was snippet of it.

Comment: @Vikas I've updated the answer to take that into account